# How to find the pattern $iperf in the file using perl

Tags: regex, perl

How can I find and display the word $iperf in a file

The file will look like this

```
$iperf -c 172.29.38.67 -m -M 64 -i 5 -t 20 -P 10
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
------------------------------------------------------------

~ $ iperf -c 172.29.38.67 -m -M 128 -i 5 -t 20 -P 10
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 172.29.38.67, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 16.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you literally want to search for and find "$iperf" or is that supposed to be a placeholder of some sort?

When you post code or a long log like this, it's courteous to use the appropriate Code or Quote format button to make it look pretty.

Comment: Voting to close because there is no question in sight.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a regex.  The string `'$iperf'` does not exist in your data, so I am going to assume you mean `'iperf'`.  You can find the lines that contain that string by looping over the file one line at a time and testing each line with a regex.  If the regex succeeds, then you can print the line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print if /\biperf\b/;
}

__DATA__
$iperf -c 172.29.38.67 -m -M 64 -i 5 -t 20 -P 10
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 64, but got 536
------------------------------------------------------------

~ $ iperf -c 172.29.38.67 -m -M 128 -i 5 -t 20 -P 10
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
WARNING: attempt to set TCP maximum segment size to 128, but got 536
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 172.29.38.67, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 16.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
```